# Typo3 V9 behind Reverse Proxy Apache2 - Backend not working

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

just updated Typo3 V9 (already running nicely behind reverse proxy) to the latest patchlevel on a test server without reverse proxy.
After migrating back everything is working fine, but I can't login to the backend. It redirects me to the internal webserver domain e.g. local.app1:8099/typo3.

I have everything set up, standard for reverse proxy. What can it be?

LocalConfig:

```
    'reverseProxyHeaderMultiValue' => 'first',
    'reverseProxyIP' => '12.345.678.90',
    'reverseProxyPrefixSSL' => '',
    'reverseProxySSL' => '*',
    'sitename' => 'Foo',
    'systemLogLevel' => 2,
    'systemMaintainers' => [
        1,
    ],
```

Best
RK

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
Strange it didn't came up elswere. We Finally found a working fix here (at least for our config):

https://forge.typo3.org/issues/91414